# Journals for tutorials

Tags: journals

I've written a paper that describes a system (for encryption), showing step by step how the system was formed. It's not a system I invented. I analyze that system and compare it with similar systems. Novel aspects include new understandings of those systems and how they relate to one-another. Can I publish this paper in a journal?

Comment: +1 I'm upvoting to cancel a down vote that isn't justified in a comment

Comment: This site suggests that downvotes should be used when: _Th[e] question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_, without evidence to the contrary, I don't see an absence of utility, clarity, nor research effort. I encourage someone else to upvote to cancel out a second down vote. (I note that asking for particular journals is off-topic, but that's not the crux of the question.)

Comment: I fear this will get closed as a "shopping" question, but before it does, I declare myself to be very interested in the answer.

Comment: @DanielHatton The OP could delete _If so, can you point to some journals?_, trivially removing the shopping aspect. (They could also delete _Do you think that this kind of work can be published in journals that publish surveys?_ Since a single question suffices.)

Comment: @DanielHatton I've edited to remove shopping aspects and vote to reopen: I see no reason to close a question due to a minor presentation issue. (The question might now be closed for being a duplicate, but that'll provide the OP with an answer.)

Comment: Thanks, @user2768.  I don't have enough rep to get a vote on close/reopen decisions, so I'll wait and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe an existing system, analyze it, and compare it with similar systems. If any of that is novel, your work is publishable, otherwise, you might be able to publish your work as a tutorial.

Comment: The novelty lies in the way I connected with other cryptosystems. Can you recommend me some journals?

Comment: Highlighting insightful connections might suffice for a conference paper or journal article in your field. I suggest asking your supervisor for guidance, if you have one. Alternatively, any contact you have at a university. (Regarding recommendations: As explained in an earlier comment of mine, shopping questions don't get answered here.)